# Swiper Pagination Bullets - Accessible for Keyboard

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I am working with a swiper.js slider.

So far it works great and i already implemented accessibility for keyboard users. Users are able to focus the arrow icons and change the slider image by pressing enter.

```
        // Swiper nav for keyboard
    $('.swiper-button-next').on('keydown', function (event){
        if(event.keyCode == '13'){
            var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;
            mySwiper.slideNext();
        }
    });
    $('.swiper-button-prev').on('keydown', function (event){
        if(event.keyCode == '13'){
            var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;
            mySwiper.slidePrev();
        }
    });
```

Now i am trying to make the pagination bullets accessible for keyboards too, but i have no clue how to start. I tryd to look up the already implemented click function for the pagination bullets, but its minified and i does not help me.

[On Click function for Pagination Bullets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQAcV.png)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself.

I have added following code to my js-file:

```
            $('.swiper-pagination-bullet').each(function (index) {
                var bullet = $(this);
                bullet.attr('id', (index + 1));
            });

             $('.swiper-pagination').each(function (){
                $('.swiper-pagination-bullet').attr('tabindex', 0);
                $('.swiper-pagination-bullet').on('keydown', function (event){
                    if(event.keyCode == '13'){
                        console.log($(this))
                        var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;
                        var slideID = $(this).attr('id')
                        mySwiper.slideTo(slideID-1);
                    }
                })
            })
```

I had to give a valid id to every pagination bullet and after that i was able to use the swiperjs slideTo()-Method to solve my problem